# Full disk encryption for UEFI non-OS GPT drives? (VeraCrypt)

Tags: disk-encryption, veracrypt, uefi

Is there a way to fully encrypt UEFI GPT non-system drives?

I'd like to use the open source successor of TrueCrypt *VeraCrypt*.

Also I'm interested in whether it also works for two drives that were virtually merged into a single drive.

Comment: It also worked for 2 merged GPT drives.

Comment: Note that it can encrypt GPT **Volumes** (partitions), as kavsrf stated, but not entire GPT drives. The difference is that it will still be obvious that you have a partition there, although it will show as "RAW".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.18 supports UEFI for boot volume

It is better to use VeraCrypt 1.20B2 from sourceforge

Ordinary data volumes on GPT disks work also.